# Annotation and Renderer Interaction

Tags: arcobjects, c#, arcgis-engine

I have code that creates either a UniqueValueRenderer or a ClassBreaksRenderer and applies it. I also have code that uses AnnotateLayerProperties to set labels.

When I create a renderer and then an annotation or an annotation and then a renderer the map goes haywire - sometimes one displays and the other one is missing and rarely (without pattern) both display.

Must I use the OnDraw event (and save the annotation instructions) to ensure that annotations are reproduced?  What can I do about the renderer?  Can I save that and restore it in the OnDraw? In what order should these be drawn?

Comment: A code example may help here.  I also suspect you're also talking about labels and not annotation although the API intermixes terminology.

Comment: Every time I look up Label it sends me to something talking about IAnnotateLayerProperties! (I quit caring what the difference was and just wrote code until what I wanted showed up.) :-> As for code: I'd have to post about 8 source files before you could even follow it.

Comment: The simple answer (if there is one) is that I started caching the renderer.  After I run the code to update the annotations (or labels or whatever they are called) I then reassign the active renderer back to the feature class and do a refresh. This (mostly) works.